# Create 404 page in SuiteCommerce

Tags: netsuite, suitecommerce

How can I create 404 page in SuiteCommerce?

I want to create 404 page template and routing regular expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these steps to create a custom 404 page:

Create a new html file that will display when the shopper encounters a 404 error

Navigate to `Documents > Files > File Cabinet`

Click Web Site Hosting `Files > Live Hosting Files > Site`

Click the Add File button to upload the html file

Navigate to `Setup > Site Builder > Domains`

For each domain to redirect to this page select the file from the Not-Found Page  drop down

Save

Answer (score 0):

He asked about SuiteCommerce not SiteBuilder.
In SuiteCommerce, you just need to override the template error_management_page_not_found.tpl (included ErrorManagement.PageNotFound.View) which is called by the ErrorManagement module.

As for the regular expressions you want to display, can you describe how should it work? Currently it's controled from the ErrorManagement.js in the method called control_valid_navigation, and this is triggered in

```
jQuery(window).on('hashchange', control_valid_navigation);
application.once('afterStart', control_valid_navigation);
```

I hope that answers your question or gives you a clue from where to start.